# Installing and running .sh file in linux mint

Tags: linux, terminal, installation

I'm using Linux mint and I want to install COMSOL. The problem is that, when I run below code in terminal, there is an error which doesn't make sense. Could anyone solve the problem?
The code I wrote:

```
./COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh
```

the error is:

```
COMSOL Server Installer Work-around Script
```

2016 TeAM SolidSQUAD-SSQ

./COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh: 14: [: Linux: unexpected operator
./COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh: 15: [: Linux: unexpected operator
-e ERROR: This script should be executed
  from the COMSOL Server installation directory
  (where comsolsetup.log resides)

[picture of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdVV.png)

COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo  COMSOL Server Installer Work-around Script
echo           2016 TeAM SolidSQUAD-SSQ
echo

# assume working dir is COMSOL installation root

COMSOLROOT="$PWD"

# check architecture

[ "`uname`" == "Linux" ] && COMSOL_TARS="fl fl_setup_glnxa64        fl_setup_maclnx fl_jvm_glnxa64 fl_glnxa64 mph_maclnx mph_glnxa64"
[ "`uname`" == "Darwin" ] && COMSOL_TARS="fl fl_setup_maclnx fl_maclnx   fl_jvm_maci64 fl_maci64 mph_maclnx mph_maci64"


# tell user he has to run the script from COMSOL Server folder

[ ! -e "$COMSOLROOT/comsolsetup.log" ] && echo -e "ERROR: This script  should be executed\n  from the COMSOL Server installation directory\n    (where comsolsetup.log resides)" && exit 1

# check if we can write to folder

[ ! -w "$COMSOLROOT/comsolsetup.log" ] && echo -e "ERROR: Cannot write     to folder \"$COMSOLROOT\".\n  If COMSOL Server was installed as root, run   this script as root too\n otherwise run it as user which made the installation of COMSOL Server!" && exit 2

# let us extract the source location and check if it accessible

COMSOLDVD="`grep "^cs.installroot" "$COMSOLROOT/comsolsetup.log" | awk  '{print $3}'`"

echo "COMSOL SERVER Installation Path = $COMSOLROOT"
echo "COMSOL Server Installation Source Path = $COMSOLDVD"

# check if source is accessible

[ ! -r "$COMSOLDVD/setupconfig.ini" ] && echo "The installaton source \"$COMSOLDVD\" id not accessible! Make sure the DVD is mounted" && exit 3

# now start untaring FL archives

for COMSOL_TAR in $COMSOL_TARS
do
tar -xf "$COMSOLDVD/archives/$COMSOL_TAR.isa" -C "$COMSOLROOT"
done

# Null the bin\tomcat\conf\login.properties

echo > "$COMSOLROOT/bin/tomcat/conf/login.properties"

# Mission complete

echo
echo All done! Enjoy!
echo

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the command with `sh` i.e. `sh ./COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh` ?

Comment: Yes, it returns the same error @SegFault

Comment: could you give me the first 16 lines of `COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh` ?

Comment: I added it to the question @SegFault

Comment: please try to replace `#!/bin/sh` by `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of your script...

Comment: I did it. But it still do not work

Comment: if  you have replaced `#!/bin/sh` by `#!/bin/bash` and the command `./COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh` (without `sh`) outputs the same initial error, maybe check that `/bin/bash` is not a link to `dash` or something...

Comment: after replacing #!/bin/sh by #!/bin/bash the remained error is : COMSOL Server Installer Work-around Script
2016 TeAM SolidSQUAD-SSQ

-e ERROR: This script should be executed
  from the COMSOL Server installation directory
  (where comsolsetup.log resides)

Comment: well, the error is self explanatory, you have to execute this script from the COMSOL Server installation directory (where comsolsetup.log resides)...

Comment: but there is no comsolsetup.log. look at the photo

Comment: Sure, you are in your `Downloads`directory. Try to find where is the COMSOL Server installation directory.

Comment: Do you know how can I find that?

Comment: Try to run this command first: `find / -name comsolsetup.log`

Comment: the answer is: find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied

Comment: And `find / -iname '*comsol*'` ?

Comment: /home/mehrana/Downloads/COMSOL_Server_Workaround.sh
/home/mehrana/Downloads/COMSOL_5.2a_Update3_DVD_Downloadly.ir.iso
/home/mehrana/Downloads/COMSOL_Server_Workaround.bat
/home/mehrana/Downloads/LMCOMSOL_Multiphysics_SSQ.lic
/home/mehrana/Downloads/Comsol_5.2a_Update3_Downloadly.ir.part2.rar
/home/mehrana/Downloads/Comsol_5.2a_Update3_Downloadly.ir.part1.rar
/home/mehrana/Downloads/Comsol_5.2a_Update3_Downloadly.ir.part3.rar
/home/mehrana/Downloads/Comsol_5.2a_Update3_Downloadly.ir.part4.rar
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied

Comment: Apparently, COMSOL Server is not installed on the local computer. You have to run this script on the server where COMSOL is installed.

Comment: I have rar files. The problem is that I don't know how to use them to install comsol

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question, please refer to COMSOL manual for installation instruction...